# Where the filters of convolutional layers come from?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

My question is about kernels or filters of convolutional layers in CNN. We can specify the filter size and how many filters there should be in one convolutional layer. But we never specify the values of filters. I know the filters are like matrix used to go through an image.

I wonder if there is an algorithm to generate the filters and optimize them during training. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main purpose of Deep convolution neural network is to learn those numbers. The so called kernel values in each filter, such that it extracts the right information from the image.

At the outset, to explain in simple terms, lets say, we have 3*3 filter,  it initially assigns all the 9 values to 0.5 . It runs over the image and produces the next level of feature map by doing the math, for simple terms lets keep it as multiplication.

It does the final layer of activation and final prediction for the probability which in turn decides the number of classes. 
If the model doesn't predict well for that batch/sample, it propagates, the loss backwards and changes the values of these kernel (9 values).Its not just these 9 values, but this process is carried out for number of filters of convolution you have at each level.

Now to efficiently make the training process, you can initialize these values through various different methods.

1. uniformly assign all as same values
2. Assign random values with constant mean and standard deviation
3. Assign random values within a range and many more.

If you are using keras, have a look at kernel intializers here https://keras.io/initializers/

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I'm looking for. In this way, you are saying the kernels are initially set randomly. During training, not only the weights but also the kernels are optimized by some particular algorithm. Am i correct?

Comment: yes. The kernel are the weights in convolution layer. If you got the answer you are looking for, please mark this as accepted answer(tick mark on the left of the answer) and feel free to up vote the answer.

Comment: Yes, I will. But I'm still wondering what the optimize algorithms are. Back-propagation is one I think for optimizing weights between layers. But for kernels, is there any algorithm?

Comment: Same back propagation updates the kernel weights also, based on the optimizers like stochastic gradient descent, Adam etc. 

To get a detailed view of the entire flow of convolution with detailed math, you can have a look at this course. http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/practicals/cnn/  which i couldnt spend much time studying this.